# How can I leverage an already existing language server in VS Code? (e.g. VS Code's native Typescript server)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So naturally when authoring an extension for VS Code, it's desirable to use a language server to do all the complex code analysis. But what if I just want to leverage that analysis? VS Code already supports Typescript and runs its own tsserver, so rather than spinning up my own, how can I speak to that server?

I can see this being broadly useful as well if it's not already a feature: to allow an extension to register a language server that other extensions can easily take advantage of.